# How can I view in-app purchase analytics from the Google Play developer console?

Tags: google-play

I had several games in the market, each with several in-app billing items.

From the Google Play Developer console, I can view which game is making the most money, and on which day, but I can't find which *item* sold the most.

I know by implementing an analytic tool like GameAnalytics or Flurry I can record that, but I would like to have a raw data from Google itself, instead of managing that using analytics.

How can I achieve this?